# How to convert sympy expression into pulp?

Tags: python, sympy, pulp

I'm getting the following error:

```
lp_problem += simplified_object _ TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects
```

Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
import pulp


objective = "x+y+z"
constraints = "x + y + z <= 5, x + 3*y - 2*z >= 3"

constraints_list = constraints.split(',')
constraints_list = [constraint.strip() for constraint in constraints_list]

cons = []

for constraint in constraints_list:
    simplified_constraint = sp.simplify(constraint)
    print(simplified_constraint)
    cons.append(simplified_constraint)

simplified_object = sp.simplify(objective)


lp_problem = pulp.LpProblem("My_LP_Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)


x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=None)
y = pulp.LpVariable('y', lowBound=None)
z = pulp.LpVariable('z', lowBound=None)


lp_problem += simplified_object  #**error here**


for simplified_constraint in cons:
    lp_problem += simplified_constraint  #**error here**
# lp_problem += y + z <=4

# lp_problem.solve()

print("Status:", pulp.LpStatus[lp_problem.status])
print("x =", x.value())
print("y =", y.value())
print("z =", z.value())
```

I printed the simplified_constraint:

`x + y + z <= 5` and `x + 3*y - 2*z >= 3`

However I don't know why the error occurs. I've tried `lp_problem += y + z <=4` and that works.

Comment: Just.... don't use Sympy? What would you expect `x + y + z` to simplify to?

Answer (score 0):

SymPy is going to return an Expr and since pulp apparently doesn't recognize that, it doesn't know what to do. I would recommend just sympifying your objective and constraints and pass them to SymPy:

```py
# your code
>>> from sympy import S, lpmax
>>> lpmax(S(objective), S(constraints))
(5, {x: 6, y: -1, z: 0})
```